# MySQL: using REPLACE with a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, replace

I need to replace *multiple* different words in a text field.

The search and replace values are in another table.

For example the texts-table is :

```
The Quick Brown Fox
The Dirty Red Bandana
```

with a replace-table like this :

```
SearchValue         ReplaceValue
  Quick               Slow
  Fox                 Wolf
  Dirty               Clean
  Bandana             Hat
```

The replaced records would then become :

```
The Slow Brown Wolf
The Clean Red Hat
```

Is it possible to do this with a JOIN?

Something like :

```
UPDATE texts_table AS tt
CROSS JOIN values_table AS vt
SET tt.Text= REPLACE(tt.Text, vt.SearchValue, vt.ReplaceValue)
```

I tried some different ways, but couldn't get it to replace *all* strings in the text field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a Join condition, for example, like this:

```
UPDATE texts_table AS tt
INNER JOIN values_table AS vt 
   on tt.valueId = vt.valudId /*or whatever the join condition*/ 
SET tt.Text= REPLACE(tt.Text, vt.SearchValue, vt.ReplaceValue)
```

As specified in the syntax of the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) clause:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
```

> The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the join. Its syntax is described [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) .

Comment: I left out the ON condition because I didn't know how to specify it, and still don't know. If I use a CROSS JOIN   (without a condition) , with 2 records in the texts_table, somehow only the LAST word in the LAST record is replaced.

Comment: @Dylan You need to specify the join clause based on the structure of your tables and what data you want to select in order to update it, `CROSS JOIN` will combine each row from the first table with each row from the second table so you got the cartesian product of the rows from the two tables so I think this won't work for you. so try  use left join or other joins.

Answer (score 0):

A `JOIN` is the wrong approach. The resulting rows of a `JOIN` are created by combining single rows from each joined table. This isn't a good match for what you want to do. For a `SELECT`, a `JOIN` combined with a `GROUP BY` would make a little more sense, though there's no `GROUP BY` clause in an `UPDATE`, so this isn't an option.

SQL isn't designed for this sort of text manipulation. It should be performed by a programming language, not a data language.

For a `SELECT`, you could force SQL to do the work by writing a [user defined](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html) [aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/udf-aggr-calling.html) function, something like:

```
/**
 * make_string: Strings hold both character sequence and a length. Strings can 
 * hold null characters and are null terminated for safety, in case they hold 
 * C-strings, but the null character shouldn't be used as a terminator by any 
 * string function.
 *
 * @param data: characters to copy to string
 * @param len: number of characters to copy from data
 * @param size: number of characters to allocate; lets you allocate extra space. 
 *     If size < len, size is set to len, so you can pass 0 to not allocate 
 *     extra space.
 */
string_t* make_string(const char *data, int len, int size);
string_t* delete_string(string_t* str);
char* string_data(string_t* str);
int string_length(string_t* str);
/**
 * Copy data to str's buffer, replacing whatever was stored there previously.
 *
 * @returns 0 on success, non-0 on failure.
 */
int string_set(string_t* str, const char* data, int len);
/**
 * Replace first occurrence of 'search' in 'str' with 'replace', starting the 
 * search at character 'start'.
 *
 * If there isn't enough space in str's buffer, resize the buffer. If there is 
 * enough space, must always succeed.
 *
 * @returns position of character after replaced section, or -1 if search isn't found.
 */
int string_replace(string_t* str, string_t* search, string_t* replace, int start);
...

my_bool group_replace_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
    if (args->arg_count != 3) {
        strcpy(message,"wrong argument count: group_replace(str, search, replacement) requires three string arguments");
        return 1;
    }
    initid->maybe_null = 1;
    initid->max_length = args->lengths[0];
    if (! (initid->ptr = make_string("", 0, args->lengths[0])) ) {
        snprintf(message, MYSQL_ERRMSG_SIZE, "error allocating string for group_replace: %s", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void group_replace_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid) {
    delete_string(initid->ptr);
}

void group_replace_clear(UDF_INIT *initid, char *is_null, char *error) {
    string_set(initid->ptr, "", 0);
    // result will be null, until 
    *is_null = 1;
    *error = 0;
}

void group_replace_add(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *is_null, char *error) {
    if (*error) {
        return;
    }
    if (*is_null && args->args[0]) {
        if (string_set(initid->ptr, args->args[0], args->lengths[0])) {
            *error = 1;
            return;
        }
        *is_null = 0;
    }
    string_t *search, *replacement;
    if (! (search = make_string(args->args[1], args->lengths[1])) ) {
        *error = 1;
        return;
    }
    if (! (replacement = make_string(args->args[2], args->lengths[2])) ) {
        delete_string(search);
        *error = 1;
        return;
    }
    int pos=0;
    do {
        pos = string_replace(initid->ptr, search, replacement, pos);
    } while (0 <= pos);
}
char* group_replace(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
                    char *result, unsigned long *length,
                    char *is_null, char *error)
{
    if (*is_null) {
        *length = 0;
        return null;
    }
    *length = string_length(initd->ptr);
    return string_data(initid->ptr);
}
```

The above:

- is untested.
- will (presumably) be case-sensitive (depending on how you implement `string_replace`), which differs from the behavior of MySQL's other string functions. For case insensitivity, implement and use a `string_ireplace` function.

Implementation of the string functions left as an exercise.

The corresponding `SELECT` statement would be:

```
SELECT tt.id, GROUP_REPLACE(tt.Text, vt.SearchValue, vt.ReplaceValue)
  FROM texts_table AS tt
    JOIN values_table AS vt ON INSTR(tt.Text, vt.SearchValue) > 0
  GROUP BY tt.id
;
```